# Angular directive for bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I write my custom directive for bootstrap popover, but face some trouble.
This is the code:

```
angular.module('CommandCenterApp')
.directive('bzPopover', function($compile,$http, $commandHelper) {
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            currencies:"=data",
            selected:"=selected"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<div class="currency-popup">' +
                '<span class="select-label">Select currency:</span>'+
                '<select class="custom-select" ng-model="selected" ng-options="currency.CurrencyName for currency in currencies track by currency.CurrencyId">' +

                '</select>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="saveCurrency()">Save</button>'+
                '</div>';
            var compiled = $compile(html)(scope);
            $(element).popover({
                content:compiled,
                html: true,
                placement:'bottom'
            });
            scope.saveCurrency = function () {
                var obj = {
                    Currency:scope.selected,
                    venueId: $commandHelper.getVenueId()
                }
                $http.post("/api/currencyapi/changecurrency", obj).success(function() {
                    scope.$emit('currencySaved', scope.selected);
                });
                //$(element).popover('hide');
            }
            scope.$watch('selected', function() {
                console.log(scope.selected);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

When I first time invoke popover all works fine, I click on button and it trigger `scope.saveChanges` function. Then I close popover and invoke it again, and directive doesnt work anymore. 
In markup popover present as:

```
<a bz-popover data="controller.currencies" selected="controller.selectedCurrency" class="change-currency hidden-xs hidden-sm" href>Change currency</a>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**: it looks like all bindings(`scope.saveCurrency`,watched on selected property) stop working after popover hidding.

Comment: Please recreate a working scenario of your directive in Plunker. It helps to find the solution faster in cases like this.

Comment: Try to explicitly define a `trigger: 'click'` or change the value to `'focus'` or something to see if that does anything.  `trigger` is a property that is returned like `replace`, `restrict`, and `link`.  But it's harder to pinpoint the problem without being able to reproduce it in a plnkr or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if this is the problem you're describing because in my fiddle I had to click twice on the button to show the popover after closing the popover.

I don't know what's the problem but with `trigger: 'manual'` and binding to click event it is working as expected.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/qbhcgn0f/).

I've commented some of your code because it's not needed to show the popover behaviour and also the ajax call is not working in the demo.

```js
angular.module('CommandCenterApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function() {
    this.currencies = [{
        CurrencyId: 1,
        CurrencyName: 'Dollar'},{
          CurrencyId: 2,
        CurrencyName: 'Euro'}];
})
.directive('bzPopover', function($compile,$http) { //, $commandHelper) {
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            currencies:"=data",
            selected:"=selected"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<div class="currency-popup">' +
                '<span class="select-label">Select currency:</span>'+
                '<select class="custom-select" ng-model="selected" ng-options="currency.CurrencyName for currency in currencies track by currency.CurrencyId">' +

                '</select>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-green" ng-click="saveCurrency()">Save</button>'+
                '</div>';
            var compiled = $compile(html)(scope);
            $(element).popover({
                content:compiled,
                html: true,
                placement:'bottom',
                trigger: 'manual'
            });
            $(element).bind('click', function() {
             $(element).popover('toggle');
            });
            
            scope.saveCurrency = function () {
                var obj = {
                    Currency:scope.selected,
                    venueId: 1//$commandHelper.getVenueId()
                }
                $http.post("/api/currencyapi/changecurrency", obj).success(function() {
                    scope.$emit('currencySaved', scope.selected);
                });
                $(element).popover('hide');
            }
            scope.$watch('selected', function() {
                console.log(scope.selected);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="CommandCenterApp" ng-controller="MainController as controller">
<button bz-popover data="controller.currencies" selected="controller.selectedCurrency" class="change-currency hidden-xs hidden-sm">Change currency</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like all working fine in your example. I'll try it tomorrow, and check as answer if all will be alright.

Comment: Hi, I try to modify code according to your answer but the behavior is the same..And I really dont understand why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self-promotion here, but you may want to take a look at the [Angualr UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) library as we've already done this for you.  And even if you don't want to use it, you can just grab the code you need...

Comment: It`s not a self-promotion, I just hadnt knew about Angular UI Bootstrap library, so I tried to make my own.