# Angular.js and Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a single page application with angular.js. The other parts are working but I could not run the rollover.
This is my controller. I am going to use on this controller.

```
    angular.module('foodDeliveryApp')
       .controller('RestaurantListController', restaurantListController);

    function restaurantListController($scope,$sce, DataService, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {

    $scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b style="color: red">hover on me as well</b>');

    $scope.hovered = function(hovering){
        $timeout(function() {
            console.log('update with timeout fired');
            if(hovering.objHovered==true){
                hovering.popoverOpened2=true;
            }
        }, 500);
    }
  }
```

The above part is popover function. 
There are a lot function for the other functionality but is not important.

```
    <span ng-init="popoverOpened1=false" ng-mouseover="popoverOpened1=true" ng-mouseleave="popoverOpened1=false">
            <button class="btn btn-default" uib-popover-html="htmlPopover"
                    popover-trigger="none" popover-placement="bottom-left" popover-is-open="popoverOpened1" >
               <span>hover me</span>
            </button>
   </span>
```

This is the HTML part in HTML which is controlling by the same controller.
Is anyone know how can I show a popover without jquery?

Comment: You could use directives here. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852728/angular-directive-for-bootstrap-popover

Comment: it has some jquery parts i just want to use angular.js

Comment: Ok, so what I understood from your above comment is you don't want Jquery and want popover in angular js. If that is the case, then I suggest you to check Angular material control for popover: https://material.angular.io/categories/modals